# How to get pass index on website

Tags: html, indexing, directory

Is it possible to get to the website directory folder (where are all those files for example index.html, page1.html...) if the main page is index.html. Is it somehow possible to ignore that index? I want to see what files are in one certain directory, but the index.html always pops up first. I hope you get what i'm trying to ask.

Comment: Most web hosts are configured to automatically load index.html if no file is specified.  You can, probably, using `.htaccess` change that configuration so that `index.html` does not load automatically.

Comment: Which web server are we talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

For Apache you can set for a directory another index this way:

```
<Directory /foo>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Not sure if I am getting right what you would like to do but, you can also turn on directory listing, it will generate a list of files in the directory /foo.

```
<Directory /foo>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```